# Sharepoint CAML query to select all items that user have shared with it

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

I secure my sharepoint list using share with, it is done by sharepoint event receiver that share the current added item with all people who could interact with that item. It works well, but when I use CAML query in my service, it brings all items. I think this happens because the IIS runs as SPPROD_ADMIN account which has all the privileges to see all the items.

How I can select all items that are shared with a specific user only using CAML query ?

Comment: Please post SharePoint related questions to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for your advice, i just posted it their.